# Getting the Error: could not find the tiller while checking the helm version

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am trying to install the helm in the kubernetes, I have installed the helm successfully.
When I check the helm version it is showing the below error

```
`helm version
Client: $version .version{SemVer:V2XXX",Git commit:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",GitTreeState:  "clean"}
Error:could not find the tiller`
```

When I executed the Init command it is showing Tiller is already installed in the cluster

`helm init --history-max 200 --service-account tiller`

```
$HELM_HOME has been configured at home/user/.helm
warning: Tiller is already installed in the cluster
```

When I check the logs for the pod I am able to see below error

`Type      Reason          Age                   From                    Message

---

Waring:   FailedCreate    11m (x25 over 132m)   replicaset-controller   error creating: pod "tiller-deploy-xxxxx" is forbidden: errorlooking up service account :tiller not found"`

How to resolve this issue any idea?

Comment: What version of helm are you trying to install? Tiller was removed in version 3 quite some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

> When I check the helm version I got the same Error

[image]

When I do the init command it is showing the same error like its already exist

```
helm init --history-max 200 --service-account tiller
```

[image]

> I am getting this error because of I am not having the service account
> To resolve this issue I have created the yaml file with service account as shown

I have created the service account using below script, this script i have taken from the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876847/clusterrolebinding-requires-namespace) and made the changes as per requirements

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","kind":"ClusterRoleBinding","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"tiller"},"roleRef":{"apiGroup":"rbac.authorization.k8s.io","kind":"ClusterRole","name":"cluster-admin"},"subjects":[{"kind":"ServiceAccount","name":"tiller","namespace":"kube-system"}]}
  creationTimestamp: "XXXXXXX"
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
```

I have deployed this service account using below command

```
kubectl apply -f filename.yaml
```

[image]

Deleted the replica set and recreated new replica sets again

```
kubectl  -n kube-system delete replicaset replica-name
```

After deleting the replica set it automatically recreates the new one

```
kubectl -n kube-system get replicaset
```

[image]

When I check the helm version I am able to see as shown below

[image]

Comment: Neither Helm nor Kubernetes will write out PNG files; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).  What specific thing should the asker do, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure tiller service account is created?

Try create the service account and giv it the required permissions

```
kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
kubectl create clusterrolebinding tiller-cluster-rule --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:tiller
```

After that initialize Helm again and see if the error goes away

```
helm init --history-max 200 --service-account tiller
```